# How to check if I have deleted my windows 10 partition when dual booting ubuntu 16

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I just attempted to dual boot Ubuntu 16 from my already existing Windows 10.

I created a new partition and then restarted my pc and booted from my usb which had the ubuntu iso installed on it.
The ubuntu installation went smoothly until I tried to boot back into windows..
My grub cannot see windows.

I tried the following:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

And it prints out:

```
Device
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda5
```

as well as a red line:

```
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary
```

Can someone please help me? I fear I may have deleted my Windows partition.

[image]

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install gparted`, then open up gparted and add a screenshot to your post.

Comment: how can I add a screen shot?

Comment: [Edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/854539/edit) your post, and look for an image icon in the edit box to add the image.

Comment: Your Windows partition is indeed deleted.  If you have files you want to get off of it, you can try using `testdisk` or [other recovery software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).

Comment: Your fear is true unfortunately. You'd have to reinstall Windows(if you want Windows back).

Comment: Before reinstalling Windows you will need to recover your valuable data. **Stop using the disk** then follow this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Actually this problem is depend on laptop company also. But don`t worry, Just press 'Ctrl+Alt+Del' it will restart then while restarting continuously press F2 or F12 then you will enter into the doss then there is option to change the operating system, you just select your windows. other wise select the secure boot you may get you windows.

Basically now days all laptops having UEFi and CSM option in the doss. for windows you can select UEFI in system configuration and for Ubuntu CSM. but UEFI is having secure boot option also.

All the best...

Comment: OP wiped his Windows partition. Please *read* the comments and/or question before answering.